# Infinite sum of prime-counting function

Tags: sequences-and-series

The function, $\pi (n) $ is the number of prime number less than or equal to $n$.

So, my question is the radius of convergence about
$$\sum_{n = 0} ^ {\infty} {\frac {1}{\pi (n)} x^n } $$

What is radius of convergence in this power series?

Comment: $1$, since $\pi(n)=\Theta\left(\frac{n}{\log n}\right)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't even need asymptotic: is't obvious $1 \leqslant \pi(n) \leqslant n$ and then using $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{1} = \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{n} = 1$ we immediately get $1$ as radius of convergence from Cauchy-Hadamard formula.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $\pi(n)\sim {n\over \log{n}}$ and $\pi(n+1)\le \pi(n)+1$

Comment: Then, Can I just approximate to $$\sum {\frac{n}{\log n} x^n}$$ ?

Comment: For the finding of radius yes.